# How do I use the $A= Pe^{rt}$ formula in this question?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So the question is 
in $2000$ the deer population in a certain area was $800$. The number of deer increases exponentially at a rate of $7%$ per year. Predict the population in $2009$.

a) $1408$

b) $1434$

c) $1471$

d) $1492$

but no matter how I try to plug in the numbers I keep getting $1502$!!! I know the answer is c but i don t get that answer no matter that i try.
I know

$p = 800$

$r= 0.07$

$t= 9 \space years$

$e = to \space  calc  \space number$

thanks for any help!!!!

Comment: You are using the calculator's $\exp$ function to calculate the value of $e^k$, correct?

Comment: yes  I am using that calculator function

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer can be computed most simply as $800(1.07)^9$.

If you really want to use PERT, the *continuous* growth rate $r$ satisfies $e^r=1.07$, so $r=\ln(1.07)$. With that value of $r$, the calculation of $e^{9r}$ will also give the right answer.

Comment: Alright then ! Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. The percentage growth in a year is not the same thing as the continuous growth rate.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the question said that the population grows exponentially?

Because if it grew exponentially, you would be correct:

$$ A = P * e^{rt} = (800) * e^{(0.07)(9)} \approx 1502 $$

But if it didn't, you would use $A = P\left(1+\frac{r}{100}\right)^t$:

$$ A = P\left(1+\frac{r}{100}\right)^t = (800)(1.07)^9 = 1471 $$

where the correct choice would be (c), as you said.